# How to manage survey model with 3 options for chose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my survey app one of the method in a model should count and group all the answers given to the survey's questions. Returned hash should have a following format - { "survey_name": { "yes": 3, "no": 2, "dont_know": 1 }}

Right now I've got working solution but well it doesn't seem very SOLID.

```
def report
statement = {
  'yes' => 0,
  'no' => 0,
  'dont_know' => 0
}
@survey.questions.each do |question|
  if question.answer&.value == 'yes'
    statement['yes'] += 1
  elsif question.answer&.value == 'no'
    statement['no'] += 1
  else
    statement['dont_know'] += 1
  end
end
{
  @survey.name => statement
}
end
```

Could you please advise how it should be done in more elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll like:

```
statement = Hash.new(0)
@survey.questions.each do |question|
  answer = question.answer&.value
  statement[answer] += 1 if answer
end
```

Initializing with `Hash.new(0)` makes that when evaluating `statement[answer]` is not defined yet, it adds the answer key to the hash with the value 0 so the `+1` after doesn't fail.

Comment: Looks good but tests are failed. When the survey has questions with answers 3 it should eq to `['dont_know']` but got 0. The same if there are no answers, `should eq to 3` but `got 0`. Additionally I think `statement = Hash.new(0)` is not necessary.

Comment: @wichru If you don't initialize `statement` with something you won't get a proper tabulation hash. Leticia's `Hash.new(0)` is the Ruby way of creating one of those.

Comment: @tadman you are right, my tests were wrong that's why they didn't worked. Sorry for that, Leticia's solution is briliant! Thank you very much!